# Automatically get the default port for request

Tags: ruby, net-http

I currently have the following code:

```
    if protocol == 'http'
      port = Net::HTTP.http_default_port()
      endpoint = Net::HTTP.new(host, port)
    else
      port = Net::HTTP.https_default_port()
      endpoint = Net::HTTP.new(host, port)
      endpoint.use_ssl = true
    end
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/item/#{item}")
    request['Authorization'] = "Bearer #{key}"
    response = endpoint.request(request)
```

Is there a way to simplify this so that I do not have to decide the default port to use for myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use ruby's dynamic dispatching.

```rb
port = Net::HTTP.send("#{protocol}_default_port")
endpoint = Net::HTTP.new(host, port)
endpoint.use_ssl = protocol == 'https'

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new("/item/#{item}")
request['Authorization'] = "Bearer #{key}"
response = endpoint.request(request)
```

**OR** in more elegant way:

```rb
path = URI('https://example.com')

Net::HTTP.start(path.host, path.port, use_ssl: path.scheme == 'https') do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new path
  request['Authorization'] = "Bearer #{key}"
  response = http.request(request)
end
```